# Is it possible to Build C program through python script?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script that finds the location of C project and copy it to my computer, I need to build that C project through my script in order to use the .exe that the project produce, is there any way to do it (to build C project automatically from python script)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [scons](http://scons.org/), which is a python framework for software building.

From the documentation:

> Open Source next-generation build tool. Improved, cross-platform substitute for the classic Make utility. In short, SCons is an easier, more reliable and faster way to build software.

[Here](http://scons.org/doc/2.5.0/HTML/scons-user/) is the user guide of the latest version, and [here](http://www.bravegnu.org/blog/make-to-scons.html) is a make-to-scons tutorial.
Scons is embeddable in a python script.

---

Another way to go, probably more a workaround than a real solution, is to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, by running compilation commands.